# How to convert an integer field to date field in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Basically my problem is the opposite of  [Transforming ArcGIS date field to integer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/transforming-arcgis-date-field-to-integer)

I have an integer field of year values (2005,2006,...)

I want to create a date field that has the value of that integer field as a year (I don't care if it is 1-1-2006). I just want the year correct.

How can I do it manually, and this shapefile has almost 7000 rows?

Is this possible?

Comment: Not only is it possible, it's under a dozen lines of ArcPy code in any of the several ways it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner in the field calculator.
Assuming you have an integer field containing the year, and another field to populate which is a date field you can follow the below example.

In my example, the year is stored in an integer field called "Created_Year" and the date field is just called "Created".

[image]

In the attribute table, right click on Created and select Field Calculator.

[image]

Set the parser to Python and type in the following:

```
time.strftime('01/01/!Created_Year!')
```

[image]

The results are:

[image]